# Can I add an additional startup folder to Word?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, templates

The [Word startup folder](https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm#PageStart) can hold custom resources for other documents such as macros or AutoText.

It's well documented how to *change* the startup folder either through Word, the registry or GPO. However, is it also possible to *add* another startup folder?

My employer has changed the startup folder through GPO from the default, user writable location (`%AppData%\Microsoft\Word\Startup\`) to another folder that holds the company templates and is not writable by a regular user (`C:\Program Files\TemplateGen9000`).
I want to add a `.dotm` file of my own to the startup folder, but I cannot write in the currently configured folder.
Can I somehow point Word to another folder that it should also read at startup (next to the GPO configured startup folder)?

I have tried loading the `.dotm` file from my user Word startup folder (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\Startup`) as one of the "Global templates and add-ins". While it would work inside the current session, it would not survive a restart of Word.

Comment: You should be able to save them in `C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I add the `.dotm` file there, it is not loaded on startup. I can add the file, then add it in the "Templates and Add-ins" window, but after a restart of Word, the `.dotm` file is listed under the "Inactive Application Add-ins" in my Word options and the file is unchecked again in the "Templates and Add-ins" window.

Comment: You will probably need to speak to you IT department then and see if they can help you. It may be they don't want you to use personal macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case both the Word and Office startup folders were unwriteable due to IT-policy, so I had to use the alternative suggested in [Charles' answer](https://superuser.com/a/1737738/141595) of adding a macro in the Normal.dotm file and load a custom template of my own.

Here are all the steps for completeness:

1. In Word check what Trusted Locations (that are writeable by the user) are configured via File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Trusted Locations:
   [image]
2. Move the `.dotm`  file to one of those locations, I chose `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\Startup`.
3. Open a new document in Word and start the VBA editor with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
4. Create a new Module under the "Normal" file (or open an existing one if it's there):
   [image]
5. Write the following macro in it:

```vb
Sub AutoExec()
'
' AutoExec Macro
'
' Load Zotero add-in from %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\Startup folder
    AddIns.Add FileName:=Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Word\Startup\Zotero.dotm", Install:=True
End Sub
```

6. Save this in the Normal.dotm file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
7. Restart Word to see that the `.dotm` file is indeed loaded (in my case the [Zotero Word plugin](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_manual_installation)):
   [image]

Note that I am a Word amateur and these steps might not be the correct way of doing things, however it does work for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Word uses two startup folders and only two. You can modify the location of one of them.**

As discussed in [my article you linked](https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm), Word actually uses two startup folders, the Word startup folder and the [Office startup folder](https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm#OfficeStartupFolder). You can modify the location of the Word startup folder. I have separate startup and user templates folders for each version of Word on my computer.

However, you can have templates in *any* folder loaded as Add-Ins upon Word's start by placing a shortcut/alias to the template in one of the recognized startup folders. If you need to use macros in them, the templates must also be in folders that are Trusted locations in the Trust center options.

The bulk of my many loaded Add-Ins are in a folder for Word 2010 and I have shortcuts for those templates in the startup folder designated in Word 2021.
[image: screenshot]
The two listed here have my custom QAT and Ribbon along with related macros and keyboard shortcuts.

An alternative, if you can add macros to your normal.dotm, would be a macro to automatically load templates in a given folder upon startup. That could be an AutoExec macro in your normal.dotm file. It could also be in a separate macro-enabled file and run manually.

Comment: OP has already stated that IT have locked down the startup folder as not writeable so shortcuts cannot be copied there.

Comment: The Office startup folder may still be available. I added a note about having a macro to load the templates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the Office startup folder resides in Program Files and is locked down as well. I was hoping I could specify a third location, which is writeable by me, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I still need to check if I can edit the normal.dotm file.

Comment: If you can write macros and have access to the Trust Center settings so you can mark a folder as trusted. You can put a macro in a macro-enabled document or template that loads your templates as Add-Ins. Ideally, it would be an AutoExec in your normal.dotm, but you could put it as an AutoOpen in a macro-enabled document.